# Docker status APIs to display status on web application

Tags: linux, api, docker

I have a requirement where I need to fetch the docker conatiner names, versions and their status whether running or stopped and display it in my web application. Is the docker provides APIs which I can utilize in web app to display all the above details?
My web application is running in a docker container and in the Linux environment.

Comment: Remember that being able to use the Docker API means it's all but trivial to root the entire host.  Be really really careful with basic security things.  (Do not try to run the `docker` shell command, for example, and if you do, absolutely do not try to construct a `docker $options command ...` string.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/) to communicate with the Docker Engine, just like the Docker CLI does.

You can use [dockernode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode) to control and query the engine via node.